# Strange CSS Exception while loading , updating and transcoding svg document using apache batik

Tags: java, svg, java-2d, batik

I am loading  svg file through following lines of code into my application

```
                                     parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();

                                     factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);

                                    // ua = new UserAgentAdapter();
                                    // loader = new DocumentLoader(ua);
                                    // ctx = new BridgeContext(ua, loader);
                                    // ctx.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.DYNAMIC);

                                    doc = factory.createSVGDocument(svg.toURI().toString());
                                    generator = new SVGGraphics2D(doc);
```

the document is generated previously with the SVG generator and it can be view in all the SVG browser and it does not contain any error.

now i am updating document

// do here height / width calculation for canvas and image itself
                Dimension d = calculateImageSize(true, true);

```
            System.out.println(" 400 DPI Original width " + d.getWidth()
                            + " height " + d.getHeight());

            generator.setSVGCanvasSize(d);

            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

            //root.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", ("0 0 " + (d.getWidth() + " " + d
                    // .getHeight())));

            NodeList imageList = root.getElementsByTagName("image");

             Node imageNode = imageList.item(0);

             Element image = (Element) imageNode;

             image.setAttributeNS(null, "width", String.valueOf(d.getWidth()));
             image.setAttributeNS(null, "height", String.valueOf(d.getHeight()));

            updateCanvas();
```

following is updateCanvas implementation

public void updateCanvas() {

```
            Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
            generator.getRoot(root);
            canvas.setSVGDocument(doc);

    }
```

now when i try to save this updated doc with following method

public void savePngImage(String pngFile, boolean is400DPI)
                        throws IOException {

```
            OutputStream ostream = null;

            try {

                    System.gc();

                    ostream = new FileOutputStream(pngFile);

                    transCoder = new PNGTranscoder();

                    if (is400DPI) {
                            transCoder.addTranscodingHint(
                                            ImageTranscoder.KEY_PIXEL_UNIT_TO_MILLIMETER,
                                            new Float(0.0635f));
                    } else {
                            transCoder.addTranscodingHint(
                                            ImageTranscoder.KEY_PIXEL_UNIT_TO_MILLIMETER,
                                            new Float(0.3528f));
                    }

                    transCoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_INDEXED,
                                    new Integer(5));
                    transCoder.addTranscodingHint(ImageTranscoder.KEY_MEDIA, "screen");

                    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(canvas.getSVGDocument());
                    TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);
                    // perform Transcoding
                    transCoder.transcode(input, output);

            } catch (TranscoderException te) {
                    te.printStackTrace();
                    throw new IOException(te.getMessage());
            } finally {
                    ostream.flush();
                    ostream.close();
            }
    }
```

with every run , the program throws random exception,

like

**** CSSEngine: exception property.syntax.error:org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "o" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.

AttrValue:auto

***** CSSEngine: exception property.syntax.error:org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.

AttrValue:auto

Exception:org.w3c.dom.DOMException
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.value.AbstractValueFactory.createInvalidIdentifierDOMException(AbstractValueFactory.java:50)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.value.IdentifierManager.createValue(IdentifierManager.java:48)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine$1.property(CSSEngine.java:744)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(CSSEngine.java:768)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(CSSEngine.java:876)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(CSSUtilities.java:82)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertVisibility(CSSUtilities.java:579)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGSVGElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGSVGElementBridge.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:208)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.TiledImageTranscoder.transcode(TiledImageTranscoder.java:61)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.savePngImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:601)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.create72DPIOriginalImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:305)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.processStyleImaging(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:226)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.traverseFolder(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:186)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.main(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:662)

***** CSSEngine: exception....
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: file:/F:/workspace/MonoGeneiousShoe/src/svg/72DPI/Style-5/Left_Style-5.svg:
The attribute "shape-rendering" represents an invalid CSS value ("auto").
Original message:
The "" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(CSSEngine.java:784)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(CSSEngine.java:876)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(CSSUtilities.java:82)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertVisibility(CSSUtilities.java:579)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGSVGElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGSVGElementBridge.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:208)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.TiledImageTranscoder.transcode(TiledImageTranscoder.java:61)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.savePngImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:601)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.create72DPIOriginalImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:305)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.processStyleImaging(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:226)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.traverseFolder(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:186)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.main(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:662)

Exception:org.w3c.dom.DOMException
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "o" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.value.AbstractValueFactory.createInvalidIdentifierDOMException(AbstractValueFactory.java:50)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.value.IdentifierManager.createValue(IdentifierManager.java:48)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine$1.property(CSSEngine.java:744)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(CSSEngine.java:768)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(CSSEngine.java:876)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(CSSUtilities.java:82)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertVisibility(CSSUtilities.java:579)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGSVGElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGSVGElementBridge.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.batik.swing.svg.GVTTreeBuilder.run(GVTTreeBuilder.java:96)
ERROR: null
Enclosed Exception:
file:/F:/workspace/MonoGeneiousShoe/src/svg/72DPI/Style-5/Left_Style-5.svg:
The attribute "shape-rendering" represents an invalid CSS value ("auto").
Original message:
The "" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.

***** CSSEngine: exception....
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: file:/F:/workspace/MonoGeneiousShoe/src/svg/72DPI/Style-5/Left_Style-5.svg:
The attribute "shape-rendering" represents an invalid CSS value ("auto").
Original message:
The "o" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(CSSEngine.java:784)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(CSSEngine.java:876)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(CSSUtilities.java:82)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertVisibility(CSSUtilities.java:579)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGSVGElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGSVGElementBridge.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.batik.swing.svg.GVTTreeBuilder.run(GVTTreeBuilder.java:96)
ERROR: null
Enclosed Exception:
file:/F:/workspace/MonoGeneiousShoe/src/svg/72DPI/Style-5/Left_Style-5.svg:
The attribute "shape-rendering" represents an invalid CSS value ("auto").
Original message:
The "o" identifier is not a valid value for the "shape-rendering" property.

***** CSSEngine: exception property.syntax.error:org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "lormal" identifier is not a valid value for the "font-style" property.

AttrValue:normal

Exception:org.w3c.dom.DOMException
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: The "lormal" identifier is not a valid value for the "font-style" property.
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.value.AbstractValueFactory.createInvalidIdentifierDOMException(AbstractValueFactory.java:50)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.value.IdentifierManager.createValue(IdentifierManager.java:48)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine$1.property(CSSEngine.java:744)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(CSSEngine.java:768)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(CSSEngine.java:876)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(CSSUtilities.java:82)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertVisibility(CSSUtilities.java:579)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGSVGElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGSVGElementBridge.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:208)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.TiledImageTranscoder.transcode(TiledImageTranscoder.java:61)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.savePngImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:601)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.create72DPIOriginalImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:305)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.processStyleImaging(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:226)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.traverseFolder(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:186)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.main(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:662)

***** CSSEngine: exception....
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: file:/F:/workspace/MonoGeneiousShoe/src/svg/72DPI/Style-5/Left_Style-5.svg:
The attribute "font-style" represents an invalid CSS value ("normal").
Original message:
The "lormal" identifier is not a valid value for the "font-style" property.
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(CSSEngine.java:784)
        at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(CSSEngine.java:876)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(CSSUtilities.java:82)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertVisibility(CSSUtilities.java:579)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGSVGElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(SVGSVGElementBridge.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:208)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.TiledImageTranscoder.transcode(TiledImageTranscoder.java:61)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.savePngImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:601)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.create72DPIOriginalImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:305)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.processStyleImaging(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:226)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.traverseFolder(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:186)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.main(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:662)
ERROR: null
Enclosed Exception:
file:/F:/workspace/MonoGeneiousShoe/src/svg/72DPI/Style-5/Left_Style-5.svg:
The attribute "font-style" represents an invalid CSS value ("normal").
Original message:
The "lormal" identifier is not a valid value for the "font-style" property.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mmg.app.svg.TiledImageTranscoder.transcode(TiledImageTranscoder.java:69)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.savePngImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:601)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.create72DPIOriginalImage(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:305)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.processStyleImaging(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:226)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.traverseFolder(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:186)
        at com.mmg.app.svg.ShoeComponentPNGCreator.main(ShoeComponentPNGCreator.java:662)

sometimes it says height is 0 , sometimes it says stroke-width is not valid attributes etc.

i think it is CSS engine related issue. what do i do wrong here ?

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution . the problem is multiple threads updates same time the canvas and that's why the exception. the solution is following code,

```
UpdateManager updateManager = canvas.getUpdateManager();

                    updateManager.getUpdateRunnableQueue().invokeLater(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
      // my update code here
}
```

Thank You